# How to create simple BASH Scripting, echo time and date

Tags: linux, bash, date, time, scripting

**how to create a bash script**
**I want to echo good morning  with time and date**

Comment: `echo "Good morning $(date)"`

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Bash tutorials abound, some research will do you good.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Good Morning, today's date is $( date )"
echo "Quote of the Day"
echo "Today I will try to be less lazy than I was yesterday"
```